# Scala convert IndexedSeq[AnyVal] to Array[Int]

Tags: arrays, scala

I'm trying to solve Codility's [GenomicRangeQuery](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/) using Scala and to that end I wrote the following function:

```
def solution(s: String, p: Array[Int], q: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  for (i <- p.indices) yield {
    val gen = s.substring(p(i), q(i) + 1)
    if (gen.contains('A')) 1
    else if (gen.contains('C')) 2
    else if (gen.contains('G')) 3
    else if (gen.contains('T')) 4
  }
}
```

I haven't done a lot of testing but it seems to solve the problem.

My issue is the for comprehension returns an `scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[AnyVal]`, while the function must return an `Array[Int]` and therefore it's throwing a `type mismatch error`.

Is there any way to make the for comprehension return an Array[Int] or transform the `IndexedSeq[AnyVal]` into an `Array[Int]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sheunis' answer above mostly covers it.

You can coerce an `IndexedSeq` into an `Array` with a call to `toArray` so the first bit's quite straightforward. For the second part, because there's a possible logical branch where you drop through all of your `if... else...` cases, it's possible for your `yield` to return both `Int` and `Unit` types, whose closest common ancestor is `AnyVal`.

Note that if you replaced your `if... else...` with pattern matching instead then you would explicitly get a compiler warning because you're not catching every possible `case`.

`` gen match {
    case _ if gen.contains("A") => 1
    case _ if gen.contains("C") => 2
    ...
    // Throws warning unless you include a `case _ =>` with no `if` clause
} ``

Comment: Thanks, that worked and I didn't need to add a default case.

Comment: "you would explicitly get a compiler warning because you're not catching every possible case" No, you won't; this only happens when matching a value of a `sealed` type and using any guards in a match expression disables the warning even in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
def solution(s: String, p: Array[Int], q: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  (for (i <- p.indices) yield {
    val gen = s.substring(p(i), q(i) + 1)
    if (gen.contains('A')) 1
    else if (gen.contains('C')) 2
    else if (gen.contains('G')) 3
    else 4
  }).toArray
}
```

The problem with the if statement is that there is no default value, which is why you get an IndexedSeq of Any instead of Int.

Comment: Calling `toArray` turns the return type into `Array[AnyVal]`, which still doesn't match `Array[Int]`

Comment: @Micho Adding an else to handle default cases will return Array[Int]. OP's original code won't since he doesn't cover all the potential cases.

Answer (score 2):

They are two problems here, the first comes from `p.indices` that returns a `scala.collection.immutable.Range` instead of an `Array`. Doing `p.indices.toArray` (or adding `.toArray` in the end like @sheunis suggested) fixes the problem.

The other issue comes from your your if statement that is incomplete, if all conditions are false, your method returns a `(): Unit` (which was there added by the compiler). Adding a default case, such as a `else -1` as a last statement should solve this second issue.

**Edit**: If the default case can never append, you could throw an exception as follows:

```
else {
  val err = "the input String can only contain the characters ACGT"
  throw new IllegalArgumentException(err)
}
```

This informs both the next programer and the compiler of what's going on in your code. Note that `throw` expressions have type `Nothing`, so when computing the least upper bound of `(Int, Int, Int, Nothing)` correctly yield `Int`, unlike `(Int, Int, Int, Unit)` that's lubed to `AnyVal`.

Comment: It's a pre-condition of the problem the input String can only contain the characters ACGT. As it happens with @sheunis answer, calling `p.indices.toArray` or calling it after the for comprehension turns the return type into `Array[AnyVal]`, which still doesn't match `Array[Int]`.

Comment: The second part of my answer explain why you get an `Array[AnyVal]` and how to fix it, see the edit for an alternative to default values.